# StreamReader cannot read from disposed object

Tags: c#, streamreader

I'm using `StreamReader`, but if try to read from the same stream using two `StreamReader`-objects I get an error saying I `can't read from dispose object (reader3.ReadLine)`.
Since I'm not disposing any object, what am I doing wrong?

```
Stream responseStream2;
FtpWebResponse ftpResponse2;

string casefile = CNCElement.ID_CASE_TEST_FILE;
string casepath;
if (FileManager.PathCombine(result, lock_root_folder, casefile, out casepath) == false)
    return false;
if (fm.DownloadFtp(result, casepath, out responseStream2, out ftpResponse2) == false)
    return false;

StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(responseStream2);
StreamReader reader3 = new StreamReader(responseStream2);
byte[] contents=null;
//if cycle is not present update case file
//if cycle is present, case file is already correct
if (reader2.ReadToEnd().Contains(cycle) == false)
{
    byte seekcase = CNCElement.ID_CASE.Value;
    int casecount = 1;
    string line;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while ((line = reader3.ReadLine()) != null
              || casecount <= seekcase)
        {
            if (line.Contains("\"\"") == true)
            {
                if (casecount == seekcase)
                    line = line.Replace("\"\"", "\"" + cycle + "\"");
            }
            byte[] app = StrToByteArray(line);
            ms.Write(app, 0, line.Length);
            contents = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

if (reader2 != null)
    reader2.Close();
if (ftpResponse2 != null)
    ftpResponse2.Close();
```

Comment: Check the streams for validity before reding from them... Besides, why would you read from the same stream twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read to the end of `reader2` you are really reading to the end of the underlying stream (`responseStream2`). At this point another read from that stream will fail.

While the specific exception is slightly expected, wrapping the same stream in different `StreamReaders` is going to do weird things because it is a weird thing to do.

If you need to read a stream twice you need to either use a stream that supports resetting its position to the beginning (ie. random access) and then create a new reader for the second read; or (as would seem likely in this case: I doubt any network stream will support random access) buffer the stream content yourself.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `ReadToEnd()` the underlying steam is all read into memory and you have reached the end.

Each time you call the function `ReadLine()` then underlying stream is moved to the next line.

This means that when your application reaches `Reader3.ReadLine()` loop, as you have already reached the end of the file, the reader fails.

If the expected file stream is not too large, I would suggest you assign the result of the `ReadToEnd()` call to a variable and perform subsequent operations on this variable.

If the stream is large, then try resetting the `Position` property (provided it is supported - [See the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.stream.position.aspx)).